# How do you prompt a user and have conditional validation in a loop for a function?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Higher Lower</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Higher - Lower</h1>

    <!--maxNum Function-->
    <!-- <p>Please enter a maximum number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="maxNum" /><br /><br /> -->
    <button onclick="userInput()">Input maximum number</button>

    <p id="ranNum"></p>

    <p id="validation"></p>

    <!--higherLower Function-->
    <p>Your Guess:</p>
    <input type="text" id="choice" /><br /><br />
    <button onclick="higherLower()">Guess</button>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <p id="values"></p>
  </body>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
function userInput() {
    let userMax=prompt("Please enter a maximum number:");
    window.alert(userMax);

    while (userMax < 1 || userMax == isNaN()) {
        alert("Maximum number cannot be negative, zero, or non-numbers");
        userInput();
    }

    // Declares new maximum number
    // let userMax=prompt("Please enter a maximum number:");
    //var userMax=document.getElementById("maxNum").value;
    // window.alert(userMax);

    if(userMax>=1) {
        alert("Maximum number set to " + userMax);
    }
    // else if(userMax<1) {
    //     alert("Maximum number cannot be lower than 1. Please try again!");
    // }
    // else if(userMax=isNaN()) {
    //     alert("Maximum number must be numeric. Please try again!");
    // }
}

function isFloat(userMax) {
    return Number(userMax) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}

function higherLower(choice) {
    // Declares random number variable
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    window.alert(randomNumber);
    // Declares user guess variable
    var guess=document.getElementById('choice').value;
    
    // Declares random number variable
    if(randomNumber==guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got it!";
    }
    else if(randomNumber>=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
    else if(randomNumber<=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    }
}
```

I am creating a simple number guessing game and finding difficulty prompting the user in a conditional loop. The loop should continue as long as the following user input conditions are met:
-zero
-negative number
-non number

I have messed around with while and do-while loops for quite a while trying to figure this out but perhaps I am missing something small to get this to work.
As a side note, I am also having difficulty finding a way to auto round-up a decimal user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that I changed.

**isNan** is a function that requires the value to be passed to it: **isNan(userMax)**

I declared userMax outside of the function so that it can be used elsewhere.

I got rid of the alerts. I added **userMax** to the random number generator to be the highest number generated.

I also updated the function to return the value from prompt.

```js
let userMax;
function userInput() {
    userMax = prompt("Please enter a maximum number:");
   
    while (userMax < 1 || isNaN(userMax)) {
        alert("Maximum number cannot be negative, zero, or non-numbers");
        userMax = userInput();
    }

    return Math.round(userMax);
}

function isFloat(userMax) {
    return Number(userMax) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}

function higherLower(choice) {
    // Declares random number variable
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * userMax) + 1;
    window.alert(randomNumber);
    // Declares user guess variable
    var guess=document.getElementById('choice').value;
    
    // Declares random number variable
    if(randomNumber==guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got it!";
    }
    else if(randomNumber>=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
    else if(randomNumber<=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Higher - Lower</h1>

    <!--maxNum Function-->
    <!-- <p>Please enter a maximum number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="maxNum" /><br /><br /> -->
    <button onclick="userInput()">Input maximum number</button>

    <p id="ranNum"></p>

    <p id="validation"></p>

    <!--higherLower Function-->
    <p>Your Guess:</p>
    <input type="text" id="choice" /><br /><br />
    <button onclick="higherLower()">Guess</button>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <p id="values"></p>
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much for explaining what you did as well. If you have any clue how to round up decimal user input, please let me know. But once again, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I am actually coming across a bug with the code you provided. Some guess attempts that fall into the appropriate range are being flagged as not being in the range. Here is the code for what I added.
if (isNaN(guess)) {
        alert("That is not a number!");
    }
    else if(guess < 1 || guess > userMax) {
        alert("That number is not in range, try again.");
    }

Answer (score 0):

First you need to wrap everything in a  if you want real built-in validation (I know you didn't ask for built-in validation but bear with me).
Real validation happens when a "submit" event is fired on a `<form>`. The normal behavior involves validation, collecting and sending data to a server, etc.

**Figure I** shows the minimal requirements in HTML needed to meet all conditions needed in OP:

**Figure I**

```html
<form>
  <input type='number' min='1' max='100' step='1' required><button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const hilo = document.forms.hilo;
// Generate a random number in the range of 1 to 100
let NUMBER = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1) + 1;
console.log(NUMBER);
// Define counter value
let count = 0;
// Bind "submit" event to <form>
hilo.onsubmit = guessNumber;

/*
Event handlers pass Event Object by default
Stop the <form> from sending data to a server
Reference all form controls (IO)
Get the value of input#guess and convert it into an integer
Determine message to display in output#message
Increase the value of output#score by 1
*/
function guessNumber(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const IO = this.elements;
  let guess = parseInt(IO.guess.value);
  let message = guess > NUMBER ? `Lower` : guess < NUMBER ? `Higher` : `${NUMBER}! You win!`;
  IO.message.value = message;
  IO.score.value = ++count;
}
// Bind <form> to the "reset" event
hilo.onreset = restartGame;

/*
Reference all form controls
Reset output#message to initial value
Reset output#score to 0
Get a new NUMBER to guess
*/
function restartGame(e) {
  const IO = this.elements;
  IO.message.value = `Guess a Number in the Range of 1 to 100`;
  IO.score.value = 0;
  NUMBER = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1) + 1;
  console.log(NUMBER);
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

p {
  margin: -2px 0 8px
}

input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit
}

input {
  width: 6ch;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 3px
}

#score {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

#score::after {
  content: ' Guesses'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Higher Lower</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='hilo'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>HiLo</legend>
      <p><output id='message'>Guess a Number in the Range of 1 to 100</output></p>
      <input id='guess' type='number' min='1' max='100' step='1' required>
      <button>Guess</button><button type='reset'>Reset</button>
      <output id='score'>0</output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```